# Program still prints when While condition is not matching

Tags: c

I want the program just to end, and not print anything. I tried putting the `printf` in the `while` loop but it didn't solve my problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int i, max;
    i = 0;
    max = INT_MIN;

    while (i >-1) {
        if (i > max) {
            max = i;
        }
        printf("give a number: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
    }
    printf("max= %d\n", max);
    return 0;
}
```

Result when I enter -2 or any negative number is `max = 0` and program ends.

Comment: return after getting negative number after scanf

Comment: why did my question get downvoted I am new to the site just wondering want to improve so I can help others and the ones who help solving my questions

Comment: Because you say things like: I want the program just to end, and not print anything. And: Result when I enter -2 or any negative number is max = 0 and program ends. If you provide a bit more context people will help you faster. Be specific. For example state your sentence like this: I want X to happen when Y is inputted. But instead Z happens when Y is inputted. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so if you want to keep printing the 'running' max until or unless the user enters a negative number, then try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    int i, max;
    i = 0;
    max = INT_MIN;

    while (i > -1) {
        printf("give a number: "); // Ask for number ...
        scanf("%d", &i);           // ... and fetch it before doing anything else!
        if (i > max) max = i;
    }
    if (max > -1) printf("max= %d\n", max); // Show max if not negative
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further explanations and/or clarification.

Comment: what if i wanted the program to print the max at the end instead of every loop and still have the condition (i >=0).

Comment: Someting like this give a number: 6     give a number: 2  give a number:-1                                                                                                                                                                                                                     max = 6

Comment: @zellez - In that case, go back to (nearly) your original code: place the `printf` statement immediately after the end of the `while` loop. (Then no need for the `if` block inside the loop, of curse¬)

Comment: I want the code to loop and ask the user about a number and then when the user wants to exit the loop he writes a negative number and then only then the printf prints the max value of the n numbers. The problem is that if the user starts the loop and then enters a negative number the printf still prints something because it is outside of the loop. If I put the pintf inside the loop it prints on every run of the loop and I dont want that. Sorry for the long comments just trying to work out my problem and thanks for the help

Comment: @zellez - OK, the code as now edited will do that! So, as long as the user has typed any non-negative number, it will display the max; if the user types a negative on the first run, then `max` will be negative and there will be no output. Have we reached "Tranquillity Base" yet?

Comment: Thanks again for the help really saved me a lot of time